# how to append css/html table in jtextpane

Tags: java, html, css, swing, jtextpane

I'm trying to 'append' an css/html table to a jtextpane.

When I do: **setText** like this:

```
        jtextpane.setText(css)
```

I get the desired result [perfect!]:

[image]

but when I try to **append** the text to the jtextpane like this:

```
        int len = jtextpane.getDocument().getLength();
        jtextpane.setCaretPosition(len); 
        jtextpane.replaceSelection(css);
```

I get the html code embedded like this: 
[image]

Q: how to append table's result (not the code) in the jtextPane? I assume I'm doing something wrong with the replaceSelection?! Thanks in advance

**EDIT - additional information:**

- To append all text information to the jtextpane I'm using the following static method:

> ```
> public static void appendToPane(JTextPane jtextpane, String userText, Color color)
> {
>   StyleContext sc = StyleContext.getDefaultStyleContext();
>   AttributeSet aset = sc.addAttribute(SimpleAttributeSet.EMPTY, StyleConstants.Foreground, color);
>   aset = sc.addAttribute(aset, StyleConstants.FontFamily, "Myriad Pro");
>   aset = sc.addAttribute(aset, StyleConstants.FontSize, 20);
>   int len = jtextpane.getDocument().getLength();
>   jtextpane.setCaretPosition(len);
>   jtextpane.setCharacterAttributes(aset, false);
>   jtextpane.replaceSelection(userText);
> }
> ```

- on instantiation of the jtextpane I have:

  jtextpane.setContentType("text/html");
- the original css string is this:

> table.imagetable {
>       font-family: verdana,arial,sans-serif;
>       font-size:11px;
>       color:#333333;
>       border-width: 1px;
>       border-color: #999999;
>       border-collapse: collapse;
>   }
>   table.imagetable th {
>       background:#b5cfd2 url('cell-blue.jpg');
>       border-width: 1px;
>       padding: 8px;
>       border-style: solid;
>       border-color: #999999;
>   }
>   table.imagetable td {
>       background:#dcddc0 url('cell-grey.jpg');
>       border-width: 1px;
>       padding: 8px;
>       border-style: solid;
>       border-color: #999999;
>   }

Comment: This likely depends on what was before it. Style tags have to go in the head of a document, if what you're appending to has closed head, then you may get problems. I don't know a lot about how Java renders HTML mind you.

Comment: If you could provide exactly what `css` is, and exactly what `jtextpane.getText()` is before the append, that would help

Comment: thanks @Cruncher, I just did.

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare what type of text you are using in the JTextPane

```
jtextPane.setContentType("text/html");
```

If this don't work, try also to include your text with correct `<html>` that should do. I had the same problem time ago, I am looking for a specific code.