# HTML Table formatting using css not working in JTextPane

Tags: java, html, css, swing, jtextpane

I am trying to implement a view only HTML pane for some specific project. I am using `JTextPane` to render HTML using content type as `"text/html"`. I was having tables in my input HTML so in order to give these tables border, i thought of using css styling, but unfortunately it did not work out.

> If I put border property as part of table itself then it works but not
>   with css styling.

Here is the sample code i created to recreate issue. **content1** does not creates border for my table but **content2** creates it. I want to use **content1** approach as i have plenty of html files with tables. Thanks for your time, any help will be much appreciated.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;


public class TestTextPane {

    private static int X = 200;
    private static int Y = 200;
    private static int W = 600;
    private static int H = 400;

    public static final String content1 = "<html>\r\n" + 
            "  <head>\r\n" + 
            "    <style type=\"text/css\">\r\n" + 
            "      <!--\r\n" + 
            "        table,th, td { border: 1px solid black }\r\n" + 
            "        body, p { font-family: Courier; font-size: 14 }\r\n" + 
            "      -->\r\n" + 
            "    </style>\r\n" + 
            "    \r\n" + 
            "  </head>\r\n" + 
            "  <body>\r\n" + 
            "    <div align=\"left\">\r\n" + 
            "      <b>Q: What is the difference between GET and POST method? </b>\r\n" + 
            "    </div>\r\n" + 
            "    <p>\r\n" + 
            "      A:\r\n" + 
            "    </p>\r\n" + 
            "    <table>\r\n" + 
            "      <tr>\r\n" + 
            "        <th width=\"50%\">\r\n" + 
            "          GET\r\n" + 
            "        </th>\r\n" + 
            "        <th>\r\n" + 
            "          POST\r\n" + 
            "        </th>\r\n" + 
            "      </tr>\r\n" + 
            "      <tr>\r\n" + 
            "        <td>\r\n" + 
            "          GET is a safe method (idempotent)\r\n" + 
            "        </td>\r\n" + 
            "        <td>\r\n" + 
            "          POST is non-idempotent method\r\n" + 
            "        </td>\r\n" + 
            "      </tr>\r\n" + 
            "      <tr>\r\n" + 
            "        <td>\r\n" + 
            "          We can send limited data with GET method and it&#8217;s sent in the header \r\n" + 
            "          request URL\r\n" + 
            "        </td>\r\n" + 
            "        <td>\r\n" + 
            "          we can send large amount of data with POST because it&#8217;s part of the \r\n" + 
            "          body.\r\n" + 
            "        </td>\r\n" + 
            "      </tr>\r\n" + 
            "    </table>\r\n" + 
            "    <br>\r\n" + 
            "    <br>\r\n" + 
            "    \r\n" + 
            "  </body>\r\n" + 
            "</html>";

    public static final String content2 = "<html>\r\n" + 
    "  <head>\r\n" + 
    "    <style type=\"text/css\">\r\n" + 
    "      <!--\r\n" + 
    "        body, p { font-family: Courier; font-size: 14 }\r\n" + 
    "      -->\r\n" + 
    "    </style>\r\n" + 
    "    \r\n" + 
    "  </head>\r\n" + 
    "  <body>\r\n" + 
    "    <div align=\"left\">\r\n" + 
    "      <b>Q: What is the difference between GET and POST method? </b>\r\n" + 
    "    </div>\r\n" + 
    "    <p>\r\n" + 
    "      A:\r\n" + 
    "    </p>\r\n" + 
    "    <table border=1>\r\n" + 
    "      <tr>\r\n" + 
    "        <th width=\"50%\">\r\n" + 
    "          GET\r\n" + 
    "        </th>\r\n" + 
    "        <th>\r\n" + 
    "          POST\r\n" + 
    "        </th>\r\n" + 
    "      </tr>\r\n" + 
    "      <tr>\r\n" + 
    "        <td>\r\n" + 
    "          GET is a safe method (idempotent)\r\n" + 
    "        </td>\r\n" + 
    "        <td>\r\n" + 
    "          POST is non-idempotent method\r\n" + 
    "        </td>\r\n" + 
    "      </tr>\r\n" + 
    "      <tr>\r\n" + 
    "        <td>\r\n" + 
    "          We can send limited data with GET method and it&#8217;s sent in the header \r\n" + 
    "          request URL\r\n" + 
    "        </td>\r\n" + 
    "        <td>\r\n" + 
    "          we can send large amount of data with POST because it&#8217;s part of the \r\n" + 
    "          body.\r\n" + 
    "        </td>\r\n" + 
    "      </tr>\r\n" + 
    "    </table>\r\n" + 
    "    <br>\r\n" + 
    "    <br>\r\n" + 
    "    \r\n" + 
    "  </body>\r\n" + 
    "</html>";

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(X, Y, W, H);

        JTextPane pane = new JTextPane();
        pane.setContentType("text/html");
        pane.setEditable(false);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(pane);
        scrollPane.setBounds(X,Y,W,H);

        frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);

        pane.setText(content2); // change content here

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: add  `tr` in style as well `table,tr, th, td { border: 1px solid black }` for content1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried all the above solutions but unfortunately any of these did not work for me. I was searching for the solution and i got into [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18701792/how-to-append-css-html-table-in-jtextpane)

And i tried `table, th, td { border-width: 1px solid black }` voila it worked for me. I dont know why the plain border property did not work for me but it worked for others.

Thanks a lot for all you help Guys.

Answer (score 1):

I removed the comment notation from the style and added units for the size of the font.

[image]

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;

public class TestTextPane {

    private static int X = 200;
    private static int Y = 200;
    private static int W = 600;
    private static int H = 400;

    public static final String content1 = "<html>\r\n" +
            "  <head>\r\n" +
            "    <style type=\"text/css\">\r\n" +
            "        table, th, td { border: 2px solid #FF0000; }\r\n" +
            // be sure to add a unit to the font size, otherwise it is invalid
            "        body, p { font-family: Courier; font-size: 14px; }\r\n" +
            "    </style>\r\n" +
            "    \r\n" +
            "  </head>\r\n" +
            "  <body>\r\n" +
            "    <div align=\"left\">\r\n" +
            "      <b>Q: What is the difference between GET and POST method? </b>\r\n" +
            "    </div>\r\n" +
            "    <p>\r\n" +
            "      A:\r\n" +
            "    </p>\r\n" +
            "    <table>\r\n" +
            "      <tr>\r\n" +
            "        <th width=\"50%\">\r\n" +
            "          GET\r\n" +
            "        </th>\r\n" +
            "        <th>\r\n" +
            "          POST\r\n" +
            "        </th>\r\n" +
            "      </tr>\r\n" +
            "      <tr>\r\n" +
            "        <td>\r\n" +
            "          GET is a safe method (idempotent)\r\n" +
            "        </td>\r\n" +
            "        <td>\r\n" +
            "          POST is non-idempotent method\r\n" +
            "        </td>\r\n" +
            "      </tr>\r\n" +
            "      <tr>\r\n" +
            "        <td>\r\n" +
            "          We can send limited data with GET method and it&#8217;s sent in the header \r\n" +
            "          request URL\r\n" +
            "        </td>\r\n" +
            "        <td>\r\n" +
            "          we can send large amount of data with POST because it&#8217;s part of the \r\n" +
            "          body.\r\n" +
            "        </td>\r\n" +
            "      </tr>\r\n" +
            "    </table>\r\n" +
            "    <br>\r\n" +
            "    <br>\r\n" +
            "    \r\n" +
            "  </body>\r\n" +
            "</html>";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(X, Y, W, H);

        JTextPane pane = new JTextPane();
        pane.setContentType("text/html");
        pane.setEditable(false);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(pane);
        scrollPane.setBounds(X,Y,W,H);

        frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);

        pane.setText(content1); // change content here

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I did aforementioned changes but still not able to get borders for table.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I tried for content1 and its working fine.

I added this line

```
body table { border: 1px solid red }
```

sample code:

```
public static final String content1 = "<html>\r\n"
        + "  <head>\r\n"
        + "    <style type=\"text/css\">\r\n"
        + "      <!--\r\n"
        + "        table, th, td { border: 1px solid black }\r\n"
        + "        body table { border: 1px solid red }\r\n"
        + "        body, p { font-family: Courier; font-size: 14; }\r\n"
        + "      -->\r\n"
        + "    </style>\r\n"
```

[image]

Comment: Tried this suggestion but not able to get the border :(

Comment: Please validate my screenshot. Is this what you want?

Comment: I just want border for my table in single color, i know it can be achieved by what you suggested but still i am not able to get it on my program

Comment: Please copy it from my post if this is what you want. change the color as per your requirement. change red to black if needed. This is more related to html css styling.

Comment: add `tr` in style as well `table,tr, th, td { border: 1px solid black }` for content1 if it's not working.